# Need a hint to get started on this algebra problem.

Tags: abstract-algebra

The problem is:

If it is known that a group G with m generators and exponent n is finite, can one conclude that the order of G is bounded by some constant depending only on m and n? Equivalently, are there only finitely many finite groups with m generators of exponent n, up to isomorphism?

I am stumped and do not know where to start. Can anyone provide me with a gentle, unrevealing hint to start this problem?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Burnside%27s_problem

Answer (score 0):

This is a famous problem known as the [bounded Burnside problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Burnside%27s_problem#Bounded_Burnside_problem).

Comment: My algebra professor played a prank on me for falling asleep during class. I was notified by my classmate that when I fell asleep, he told the class he wanted me to think this was homework and he told them to play along. I am a little disappointed given that I have spent nearly fifty hours the past week trying to solve this problem, neglecting all my other assignments.

Comment: Well, dat sux. Try not to fall asleep next time :). I also had a rough time in my number theory class last semester because I played flappy bird all the time. Now I learned my lesson.